# I don't understand what is my problem Firebase?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, spring-webflux, flutter-test

```
One or more plugins require a higher Android SDK version.
Fix this issue by adding the following to C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\tour\android\app\build.gradle:
android {
  compileSdkVersion 33
  ...
}


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.android.material:material:<version>.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/material/material/<version>/material-<version>.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/android/material/material/<version>/material-<version>.pom
       - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/google/android/material/material/<version>/material-<version>.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/material/material/<version>/material-<version>.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
```

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your compileSdkVersion is low try to increase it to 33 to do this:

open the android/app/build.gradle file in your project, and find the android block. Inside this block, you should see a compileSdkVersion setting. This setting specifies the version of the Android SDK that your app is built against. The error message indicates that you need to update this setting to a higher version (currently 33) to fix the issue.

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 33
  // Other settings here...
}
```

and rebuild your app